# Docker container with a shell script ignores SIGTERM

Tags: bash, docker, shell

I have a very simple Docker container which runs a bash script:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4

FROM alpine:3
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    curl bash sed uuidgen

COPY demo.sh /app/demo.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/*.sh

CMD ["bash", "/app/demo.sh"]
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Test 123.."
sleep 5m
echo "After sleep"
```

When running the container with `docker run <image>` the container cannot be stopped with `docker stop <name>`, it can only be killed.

I tried searching but everything with "bash" and "docker" leads me to managing docker on host with shell scripts.

Answer (score 4):

`sleep` is an example of an uninterruptible command; your shell never receives the `SIGTERM` until `sleep` completes.

A common workaround is to run `sleep` in the background, and immediately wait on it, so that it's the shell built-in `wait` that's running when the signal arrives, and `wait` *is* interruptible.

```
echo "Test 123..."
sleep 5 & wait
echo "After sleep"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add this before the sleep statement ?

```
trap "echo Container received EXIT" EXIT
```

Or do `docker stop -t 5 container` for example.